# How can I check user had registered and match data between data on firebase authentication and firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

this is my first time to ask in StackOverflow. So that, I would like to share  a problem in this forum. I've had registered an account to firebase authentication and record that on Firebase Realtime-Database. You can see on these pictures

https://i.ibb.co/TcqDhF7/image.png

https://i.ibb.co/Zc1YnLY/image.png

The problem is on Login. When I logged in, I expected that Firebase can match data between authentication and database but that was opposite. the question is Can Firebase match user data between authentication and the data record on Database?

I've tried to modify my Login Activity class like this

LoginActivity.java

```
package id.co.dolansemarang.loginfirebaseds;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnLogin;
    EditText edtEmailLogin, edtPasswordLogin;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuthLogin;
    DatabaseReference userRefLogin;
    FirebaseUser curUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        edtEmailLogin = findViewById(R.id.edt_email_login);
        edtPasswordLogin = findViewById(R.id.edt_password_login);
        firebaseAuthLogin = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        curUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String email = edtEmailLogin.getText().toString();
                final String password = edtPasswordLogin.getText().toString();

                if (email.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Masukkan email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    if (password.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Masukkan password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        firebaseAuthLogin.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                    userRefLogin = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(curUser.getUid());
                                    userRefLogin.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                                //ambil data password
                                                String passwordFromFirebase = dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue().toString();
                                                //validasi password dengan password di edit text
                                                if (password.equals(passwordFromFirebase)) {
//                                                    menyimpan data ke local storage (handphone)
//                                                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(USERNAME_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
//                                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
//                                                    editor.putString(username_key, etUsername.getText().toString());
//                                                    editor.apply();
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

                                                } else {
                                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Pasword tidak cocok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }

                                            } else {
                                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username tidak terdaftar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Pasword tidak cocok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });

                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Pasword tidak cocok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.w("Pesan", "Gagal Masul");
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I expect firebase can check matchable password and email data on both of them so that when I login app, Firebase check email and password on Firebase auth and database
.
I need help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> firebase will  check it Self User is Authenticated or not so you  can not
  to check Manually.




 private void loginUserWithFirebase(String email, String password) {
           firebaseAuthLogin.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                   .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                           if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                               startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));



 }
                           else{

                               Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }
                       }
                   });
       }
```

Comment: you are saying correct and i a doing the same, but sometimes user created in authentication but not in my realtime database which gives user an error that account already exists. How do i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

here you can find the email id is registered or not :-

```
    private void loginUserWithFirebase(String email, String password) {
           firebaseAuthLogin.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                   .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                           progressDialog.dismiss();
                           if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                               // here is user registered
                               startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                           }
                           else{
                               // here if your is not registered or any elese error will show
                               Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }
                       }
                   });
       }
```

Comment: Hello, it is nice to meet you before. Thank you for helping me to asnwer my question.  So, although I record registered data  on Realtime-Database, Doen't effect to data on Firebase Authetication?

Comment: you don't need to check in firebase database is the user registered or not. The firebsase will return the exception if that user want to login is registered or not

Comment: try my code and comment your code to check and enter the wrong credentials in your login actvity

Comment: I would like to apologize for missunderstanding of my last comment so that, I change my question. So, I can enter the code to match register account with data on firebase database?

Answer (score 0):

Once you logged in get the user Uid and then make a call to the realTime database with that id if the datasnapshot is null so the user didn4t register yet , else you can retrieve the user sence he has registered . i do it like this:

```
 DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users/"+uid);
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //Log.d("dataSnapShotValue",""+dataSnapshot.getValue());
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue()!=null){
              // User exist
            }else{
              //  user dosn't exist
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
        }
    });
```